# M1.9 Translation string with link in csv

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation, translate

In my login.phtml I have a custom string containing a link and I do not succeed to translate it with the translate.csv of my custom theme.

```
'If you are private customer please visit our <a href="https://www.my-link.com" class="my-link" target="_blank">Shop</a> for home-users.'
```

Can anyone help?